# Connection from VSCode Remote-Container to AWS CodeCommit repository fails due to default settings

Tags: git, docker, visual-studio-code, aws-codecommit, vscode-remote

I'm using amazon linux 2 as the OS image.
I want to connect to my AWS CodeCommit repository using HTTPS protocol with my default credentials.

Connection from a container on VSCode Remote-Containers to AWS CodeCommit repository fails due to default settings.

When connect to CodeCommit repository I use ~/.gitconfig file with below setting.

> [credential] helper = !aws codecommit credential-helper $@

But VSCode have default setting on '/usr/etc/gitconfig'.

> [credential] helper = "!f() { command -v code >/dev/null 2>&1 && code --gitCredential $*; }; f"

So my config is ignored.

If I remove the file '/usr/etc/gitconfig' on my container,
I can connect to my CodeCommit repository.

But when I reload the VSCode window, the file is restored every time.

I wrote the command on the file .devcontainer/devcontainer.json

> "postCreateCommand": "rm /usr/etc/gitconfig"

It didn’t seem to work.

I want to ignore the default setting or overwrite it by my code permanently.

Comment: Where's this setting? I couldn't find it anywhere in `vscode`

Comment: thanks for reading. it's appears on the container on VSCode Remote-Containers extension.

Comment: I wrote bellow command in my .bashrc and it works so far but I don't think this is the best.
[ -e /usr/etc/gitconfig ] && rm /usr/etc/gitconfig

Answer (score 1):

I wrote bellow command in ~/.bashrc and it works so far but I don't think this is the best solution.

> [ -e /usr/etc/gitconfig ] && rm /usr/etc/gitconfig